# TypedData signature using Quorum Key Manager is failing/not verified

Tags: ether, openzeppelin, quorum, meta-transactions, keymanagement

I am trying to create a TypedData transaction using OpenZeppelin Defender. I am using the OpenZeppelin MinimalForwarder to verify the authenticity of the signer.

To create the signature, I am using Quorum Key Manager and then I am passing the signature to the forwarder to carry out the transaction. But to my concern it seems the signature is not being verified by the forwarder. I am guessing that the either the TypedData Object is messed up or algorithm+curve used by Quorum Key Manager is different.

I have attached the API reference of QKM here  -
[https://consensys.github.io/quorum-key-manager/#tag/Ethereum/paths/~1stores~1%7BstoreName%7D~1ethereum~1%7Baddress%7D~1sign-typed-data/post](https://consensys.github.io/quorum-key-manager/#tag/Ethereum/paths/%7E1stores%7E1%7BstoreName%7D%7E1ethereum%7E1%7Baddress%7D%7E1sign-typed-data/post)

This is my typedData payload

```
const EIP712Domain = [
  { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
  { name: 'version', type: 'string' },
  { name: 'chainId', type: 'uint256' },
  { name: 'verifyingContract', type: 'address' },
];

const ForwardRequest = [
  { name: 'from', type: 'address' },
  { name: 'to', type: 'address' },
  { name: 'value', type: 'uint256' },
  { name: 'gas', type: 'uint256' },
  { name: 'nonce', type: 'uint256' },
  { name: 'data', type: 'bytes' },
  { name: 'validUntilTime', type: 'uint256' }
];

const payload = {    
  types: {
    EIP712Domain,
    ForwardRequest,
  },
  domainSeparator: {
    chainId,
    name: 'MinimalForwarder',
    verifyingContract,
    version: '0.0.1',
  },
  messageType: 'ForwardRequest',
  message: { from, to, data, value, gas, nonce }
}


const signature = await axios.post(`http://localhost:8080/stores/eth-accounts/ethereum/${userAddress}/sign-typed-data`, data, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }).then(res => res.data).catch(e => { console.log(e) });

const args = [
   payload.message,
   signature
]

const verify = await forwarder.verify(...args);
```